# Running Linux commands execute hidden command to regenerate Backdoor

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring, editors, binary

My CentOS server compromised, the backdoor uploaded in /var/www/html/, I have deleted the backdoor and browsed the backdoor - to be sure it's deleted - it's surly deleted, but when I run any command such as "ls", "ps"... in any dictionary, the backdoor file generated again.

I noticed the files /usr/bin/ls , /usr/bin/ps ... has been modified in the same day of the attack.

After long auditing by using ( auditctl and ausearch to be clear) for finding which process generating the backdoor after deleting it, this is the results.

```
time->Sat Jan 13 17:44:37 2024
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978): proctitle=726D002D69002F7661722F7777772F68746D6C2F6D61676E69746F2E706870
type=PATH msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978): item=1 name="/var/www/html/xx.php" inode=35084690 dev=fd:00 mode=0100777 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 objtype=DELETE cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
type=PATH msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978): item=0 name="/var/www/html/" inode=34033743 dev=fd:00 mode=040775 ouid=995 ogid=995 rdev=00:00 objtype=PARENT cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978): arch=c000003e syscall=263 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffffffffffff9c a1=1e670c0 a2=0 a3=7ffcc4acfea0 items=2 ppid=8050 pid=9434 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=193704 comm="rm" exe="/usr/bin/rm" key=(null)
----
time->Sat Jan 13 17:45:07 2024
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995): proctitle=6C73002D2D636F6C6F723D6175746F002F
type=PATH msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995): item=1 name="/var/www/html/xx.php" inode=35084690 dev=fd:00 mode=0100644 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 objtype=CREATE cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
type=PATH msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995): item=0 name="/var/www/html/" inode=34033743 dev=fd:00 mode=040775 ouid=995 ogid=995 rdev=00:00 objtype=PARENT cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7f22b8e630f9 a1=242 a2=1b6 a3=24 items=2 ppid=8050 pid=9465 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=193704 comm="ls" exe="/usr/bin/ls" key=(null)
```

I want to know how do correct monitor and find the execution command that used to generate the backdoor by running any Linux commands or if there is a way to modify and inject these files /usr/bin/ls, /usr/bin/ps...

Comment: If you're doing this merely as an academic exercise, it's fine to proceed, but if you are trying to recover the webserver it will need restored from a backup or rebuilt. That they were able to modify files in /usr/bin implies you are running the webserver as root, so there isn't a good way to ensure the server is safe again.

Comment: See also the usual SF Q/A about this: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: @cutrightjm i'm doing this as an exercise, my server already offline and i'm interested to know how /usr/bin can be linked or injected with other commands, I was looking into inject binary files ,seems thats a possible way to have same result , but still can't catch the injected codes inside my server files.